# where from a column that does not exist in the table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a sql query, I need to do a comparison where of a column that I am renaming based on certain conditions, but I get an error that the column does not exist, how can I do this?

```
select e.emp_nombre, nvl(e.emp_activo,1) as nivel
from gen_empresa e
where nivel = 1;
```

Comment: After fixing the error (as shown in the posted Answer) - what is the point of including the `nvl(..., 1)` in the `SELECT` list? The value will be 1 for all rows in the output (because that's what the `WHERE` clause requires), so why do you need to include it in the output?

Comment: the truth I put it only as an example, it could be a more extensive sql query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the column alias in the WHERE clause, because WHERE clause is evaluated before the column alias is created.

Either use the same `nvl(e.emp_activo,1)` expression in the `WHERE` clause:

```
select e.emp_nombre, nvl(e.emp_activo,1) as nivel
from gen_empresa e
where nvl(e.emp_activo,1) = 1;
```

Or use a *derived table*:

```
select emp_nombre, nivel
from
(
    select e.emp_nombre, nvl(e.emp_activo,1) as nivel
    from gen_empresa e
)
where nivel = 1;
```

Comment: I wanted to simplify the sql statement, because if in my alias I have a very extensive sql I would have to rewrite it inside my where clause, I would think that it is a lot of work for the DB.

Answer (score 1):

You can also write your query as CTE:

```
WITH TMP AS (select e.emp_nombre, nvl(e.emp_activo,1) as nivel
from gen_empresa e)
Select * from TMP where nivel=1;
```

Comment: I find your answer interesting, would it work only for oracle or for other db administrators like postgresql?

Comment: @LUISFERNANDOGUERREROORTEGA - The `WITH` clause (subquery factoring, CTE, it's called different things) is in the SQL Standard. Most (if not all) database management systems support it. It has a very important and powerful extension, known as recursive WITH clause (recursive subquery factoring, recursive CTE) - **not related** to your question; that is also in the SQL Standard, but fewer database management systems support it. Oracle db does.